# I am getting error as "The method executeScript(String, Object[]) in the type JavascriptExecutor is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am getting error as "The method `executeScript(String, Object[])` in the type JavascriptExecutor is not applicable for the arguments `(String)`" please help me to solve.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("twotabsearchtextbox")).sendKeys(new String[] {"Books"});
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.className("nav-input")).click();
        System.out.println("Books");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
        jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 100)");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("s-ref-checkbox-9141482031")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your line:

```
jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 100)");
```

Only takes in a String as a parameter but it needs to take in a String and an Array of Objects. It needs a second parameter.

Comment: I changed as  jse.executeScript("scroll(0, 100)", null); ...Whether it is correct or not ? since browser not responds anything when run this code

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
jse.executeScript("scroll(0,250);");
```

for **scroll down**.

for **scroll up**, no need to change x coordinate , just change the Y coordinate to negative.